# How to enable/disable Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, anchor

Below example is working for enable/disable of href but not for **onclick**. I need to enable/disable for both attributes

Note: I cant simply remove/bind the onclick event to dummy function() as it need once we enable it.

Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#b1").click(function () {
         $("#yahoo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
         $("#yahoo").css("background-color", "silver");
     })

     $("#b2").click(function () {
         $("#yahoo").removeAttr("disabled");
         $("#yahoo").css("background-color", "white");
     })

     $("#yahoo").click(function (e) {
         if ($("#yahoo").attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
             e.preventDefault();
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
 <div>
   <input type="button" id="b1" value="Disable Yahoo Link"> 
   <input type="button" id="b2" value="Enable Yahoo Link">    
 </div>    
 <a id="yahoo" target="_blank" href="javascript:alert('href alert')" onclick="javascript:alert('onclick alert')">Yahoo.com</a>
```

Working Example
http://jsfiddle.net/nunnakirankumar/suYe4/

Comment: You don't need the `javascript:` scheme in the `onclick` handler, since you're already in a JavaScript context. The only reason it works is because in this case `javascript:` is being treated as a label.

Comment: agreed @Kolink but removing of label    javascript: didnt solved my problem.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. I'm using IE10.

Comment: Works in IE but no in FF (FireFox).

Comment: Try `if( this.hasAttribute("disabled"))`

Answer (score 9):

Inside your click() function, you need to explicitly return false (after discovering it's disabled).  Otherwise the default handler will cause the browser to go to or run the designated href.

The OP has most likely moved on, so this answer is really just for google searchers' sake.