# How to avoid text in anchor tag is javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

Text of anchor tag is dynamic data. If it's javascript, button,...
I don't want javascript... work, only display it is text. How to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a id="myAnchor" href="#" readonly="readonly">data</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Ex: data is

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="#"onclick="return false;"><script>alert("aaaa")</script></a>
```

Comment: Add `onclick="event.preventDefault()"` on anchor. OR `onclick="return false;"` OR `href="javascript:void(0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable Anchor Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657351/how-to-enable-disable-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the demo `

```html
<a id="myAnchor" href="#"onclick="return false;"><xmp> <script>alert("aaaa")</script> </xmp></a>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is not to execute the `script` tag inside the anchor element, in that case, you need to escape the element tag syntax so that the anchor tag becomes

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="#">&lt;script&gt;alert("aaaa")&lt;/script&gt;Javascript</a>
```

If you are using some server side template language to generate the html, then it should have some facility to escape the html content